# Cannot link to custom Qt widget

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new to Qt and am trying to figure out how to add a custom widget I've created to my main window.

The widget is pretty simple - I just used Qt Designer to create the default widget (I'm calling it Editor) and then added a button to it.  Next I included the header of my custom widget in mainwindow.h and added a pointer to it in my MainWindow class.  So far, so good.  But when I try to create a new instance of Editor, I get the error:

```
mainwindow.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl Editor::Editor(class QWidget *)" (??0Editor@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl MainWindow::MainWindow(class QWidget *)" (??0MainWindow@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z)
```

What do I need to do to be able to link my code?

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

#include "editor.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    Editor *editor;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    editor = new Editor(0);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;

    delete editor;
}
```

editor.h:

```
#ifndef EDITOR_H
#define EDITOR_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class Editor;
}

class Editor : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Editor(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Editor();

private:
    Ui::Editor *ui;
};

#endif // EDITOR_H
```

editor.cpp:

```
#include "editor.h"
#include "ui_editor.h"

Editor::Editor(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Editor)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Editor::~Editor()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

CustomWidgetTest.pro:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = CustomWidgetTest
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    editor.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    editor.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui \
    editor.ui
```

Comment: Try to run qmake and build again.

Comment: Ah, I need select Build/Run qmake from the Qt Creator menu rather than run it from the command line.  That worked.

Comment: Running qmake is also supported in the build menu of creator, so you do not have to run it from shell. You need to do this whenever you change fundamental things in your project, as qmake rebuilds your makefile, which needs to be done, if you add header files which contains classes with Q_OBJECT. Or if you change project settings in the .pro file.

Comment: Your Editor won't appear, unless you put it in a dialog and call exec or you put the editor somewhere in a layout or a widget of your main window layout. Simply adding a pointer will not show anything.

Comment: Yes, I realize that.  I was having problems simply linking the file, though, and was not able to go further with the code.